# How to make a progressbar show in a fragment from an Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter

So I have these 4 things.

- A Fragment that has my progress bar
- In that fragment there is a recycler view.
- That recyclerview is being handled by an Adapter
- In that adapter, I have a button `onclick` listening, which when I press the button, will fire off a query on the Firestore database.

What I want to happen is when I click the button and while async tasks are taking place, I want it to show a progress bar.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: What have you tried? take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: create an interface with methode on click implement you fragment with that interface and pass that reference in adapter and upon click on button call to that interface method to show progress or hide